# Removing overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology, overlapping-features

How do I remove overlapping polygons in QGIS 3?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried `v.clean` (`bpol`, `rmdupl` and `rmarea` using right tolerances) and when I check the topology after doing that it says there is no overlapping but I can still see overlapping polygons. As a result I would like something like that last picture.

Comment: Not sure why you used v.clean, but if you just want to find the overlapping polygons simply run an Intersection with the same layer as input and overlap features. Wherever there are multiple features for a given ID in the input layer = overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i just want to delete the overlapping area not the whole polygon plus there would be a lot of them so using that method would take me a lot of time to find and delete all of them.

Comment: How do you decide which polygon part to delete? In last picture, you've deleted the overlapping area of lower polygon. Why not the upper polygon?

Comment: It doesn't matter I just want them not to overlap, I don't care if its that way or the other.

Comment: Are your overlapping polygons in the same layer, or different layets?

Comment: in the same layer

Comment: If the clean had worked properly you would have no overlapping polygons in the new polygon layer, each pror overlap area becoming a new polygon with the attributes of one or the other previously overlapping polygons randomly assigned. If each polygon in the original layer had a unique attribute, then after running the clean you could dissolve that layer on that attribute to merge those new "overlap" polygons with the adjacent poly of the same attribute. I do not know of any single tool in QGIS or ArcGIS which will convert overlap areas in a layer to one or the other abutting polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution by means of Processing tools so far. If you prefer a python code, use the following script [using QGIS Python Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor).

First, backup the layer. Because the script changes polygon's geometry in place, it doesn't create new layer. Then select the layer and run the script.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f1 in layer.getFeatures():
    for f2 in layer.getFeatures():
        if f1.id() < f2.id():
            geom1 = f1.geometry()
            geom2 = f2.geometry()
            new_geom = geom2.difference(geom1)
            layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({f2.id(): new_geom})
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll try it later. I'm thinking I need to learn Python, seems so useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tool *clip* from the menu *Vector > Geoprocessing tools* (see. [Vector overlay - Clip](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisclip)).

You can use the tool with an identical input and overlay layer. I just checked again and it at least does, what you show in your last picture. However, as Kadir Şahbaz pointed out in his comment, it is hard to find an automatic tool, to correct a specific geometry in a specific way. If that is not an issue for you, that should do the trick for you.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but just tried and it does not work for me when using the same layer as input and overlay.

Comment: Same here, it doesn´t work. The thing is that deleting overlapping polygons shouldn`t be that hard to do but its been 3 days researching and i haven't found any good solution. Thank for all the help by the way.